# Ruby Class Singleton method returns self, why?

Tags: ruby

I have been using a couple of Ruby libraries (Vault from Hashicorp) and (Diplomat from WeAreFarmGeek) that use the Singleton Class paradigm where the Class itself is as an universal way to access the underlying client functions. Within a framework like Chef I see the upside of this as once the class is properly configured it is available to all cookbooks.

I wanted to understand the mechanics of how this is done and have read and pretty much understand what at least the ruby-vault code is doing. There is however, one line of code that I can not understand the function of. I was hoping someone here may be able to explain it to me.

If you look at the code snippet below from (https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-ruby/blob/master/lib/vault.rb) you will see that when the library is required the `setup!`
method is called which "creates" a new client which via method_missing allows the Class itself to function as the client.

The one part of the code that I do not understand is why the `setup!` method needs to return `self`. I have looked at the entire module code base and the top level file is the only place that setup! is called so I fail to grok why the authors choose to return `self`. That is the question.

Thanks!

```
module Vault
  require_relative "vault/errors"
  require_relative "vault/client"
  require_relative "vault/configurable"
  require_relative "vault/defaults"
  require_relative "vault/response"
  require_relative "vault/version"

  require_relative "vault/api"

  class << self
    # API client object based off the configured options in {Configurable}.
    #
    # @return [Vault::Client]
    attr_reader :client

    def setup!
      @client = Vault::Client.new

      # Set secure SSL options
      OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:options].tap do |opts|
        opts &= ~OpenSSL::SSL::OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS if defined?(OpenSSL::SSL::OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS)
        opts |= OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_COMPRESSION if defined?(OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_COMPRESSION)
        opts |= OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv2 if defined?(OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv2)
        opts |= OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv3 if defined?(OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv3)
      end

      self
    end

    # Delegate all methods to the client object, essentially making the module
    # object behave like a {Client}.
    def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
      if @client.respond_to?(m)
        @client.send(m, *args, &block)
      else
        super
      end
    end

    # Delegating +respond_to+ to the {Client}.
    def respond_to_missing?(m, include_private = false)
      @client.respond_to?(m, include_private) || super
    end
  end
end

# Load the initial default values
Vault.setup!
```

Comment: The return value is never used so it doesn't have a specific reason. In general, returning `self` is a way to implement a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this and respond. Much appreciated.